# Не срабатывает скрипт jQuery

Tags: jquery

Для html-кода

```
<div class='view-source'>
    <h3><a href="#">Заполнить на сайте</a></h3>
    <div id="hide">
        <p>Текст</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

прописывается скрипт, чтобы по клику на ссылке под ним раскрывался текст

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Раскрывающийся список
        $(".view-source #hide").hide();
        $(".view-source a").toggle(

        function () {
            $("#hide").slideDown(500);
        },

        function () {
            $("#hide").slideUp(500);
        };

        });
</script>
```

но он не срабатывает, текст в диве с `id="hide"` отображается на странице в развернутом виде. Подскажите, что с ним неправильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Форматируйте код** — будет легче читать и заметить ошибки. Скобку `toggle(...` не закрыли после второй `function(){...}`, и `;` не на своём месте была. Вот так — [работает](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/GD628/):

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        //Раскрывающийся список
        $(".view-source #hide").hide();
        $(".view-source a").toggle(
            function(){
                $("#hide").slideDown(500);
            },
            function(){
                $("#hide").slideUp(500);
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Comment: о, большое спасибо) а то я уж думала, скрипт неправильный.